# Batch file takes three runs to set the environment variables correctly

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have the following batch file to set the required environment variables:

```
setx -m APPS_DRIVE "E:"
setx -m APPS_HOME "%APPS_DRIVE%\Apps"
setx -m DOMINO_HOME "%APPS_DRIVE%\Lotus\Domino"
setx -m PRODUCT_HOME "%APPS_DRIVE%\Product"
setx -m JAVA_HOME "%APPS_HOME%\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"
```

The problem here, is that I need to run the batch file thrice to have all the variables set up correctly. In the first run, only APPS_DRIVE gets set as **E:\**

The others like APPS_HOME for instance shows up as **\Apps**

Then in the second run, my APPS_HOME gets set correctly but not the other 3. And in the 3rd run, all the variable are reflected correctly.

I see what the command line is doing, I just don't get why? Since the commands are executed sequentially, one after the other.

Is this the intended behavior? If so, is there any workaround to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setx updates the registry , but the cmd.exe gets the information from the registry when it starts.
So setx effect is visible after restarting the command prompt.But you can try this:

```
setx -m APPS_DRIVE "E:" & set "APPS_DRIVE=E:"
setx -m APPS_HOME "%APPS_DRIVE%\Apps" & set "APPS_HOME=%APPS_DRIVE%\Apps"
setx -m DOMINO_HOME "%APPS_DRIVE%\Lotus\Domino"
setx -m PRODUCT_HOME "%APPS_DRIVE%\Product"
setx -m JAVA_HOME "%APPS_HOME%\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"
```

Or beter:

```
  if not defined APPS_DRIVE (
      setx -m APPS_DRIVE "E:" & set "APPS_DRIVE=E:"
  )
```

And so on for every variable

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Since the APPS_DRIVE and APPS_HOME are the two key directories, I think I'll only add the & for them right? Since the rest are dependent on just these two. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: Works like a charm. I was almost there looks like, I thought a session related variable need to be set, so I used setx as opposed to setx -m. Thanks for your help. PS: There's a slight typo in the first line where set is part of the inverted commas.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you issue `setx -m APPS_HOME "%APPS_DRIVE%\Apps"` while `APPS_DRIVE` is not yet defined in the current session, the variable in the registry will be set to that exact string, without expanding `%APPS_DRIVE%`. *This is a good thing!* On your next login, all variables will be correct, any you can change the DRIVE of all of them by simply changing `APPS_DRIVE`, which the others reference.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, this wouldn't be too useful on a server machine right? Since it's barely ever restarted and these setups would need to be done at the time the server is started. I'm hoping I made sense there.